# Wilson's theorem states that if n is a prime number, it will divide (n-1)! + 1, using this find the smallest divisor of 12!+6! +12!×6! + 1?

Tags: real-numbers

> Wilson's theorem states that if $n$ is a prime number, it will divide $(n-1)! + 1$, using this find the smallest divisor of $12!+6! +12!×6! + 1$?

I checked yahoo answers and there someone gave the answer as $7$(which is wrong). The answer is $91$. Please explain the method.
Thanks

Comment: $91=7\times 13$ isn't prime.  It's not the smallest divisor of anything.

Comment: The method is this: $12! + 6! + 12!\times 6! + 1 = (12! + 1)\times (6! + 1)$, so Wilson's theorem states that $7$ and $13$ divide it.  And it is equal to $1$ modulo $6!$, so it's not divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$.  Its smallest divisor is therefore $7$.

Comment: @Arthur it is mod 6!, so mod 720. Then it does say something about 5.

Comment: Some rewording may be useful. The smallest (positive) divisor of our number is $1$,

Comment: To see that $91$ isn't prime, $91=10^2-3^2=(10-3)(10+3)=7\times 13$.

Comment: You really don't need to include a statement of Wilson's theorem in your title.  It makes it appear that you put no effort at all into even formulating your question, let alone trying to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\,f(x)\,$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $\,\color{#c00}{f(0) = 1},\ \color{#0a0}{f(-1) = 0}\,$ then the prime $\,p\,$ is the least factor $> 1$ of $\,f((p\!-\!1)!)\, $ since, $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\ f((p\!-\!1)!)\equiv \color{#0a0}{f(-1)\equiv 0}\,$ by [Wilson,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) and if prime $\,q< p\,$ then $\,q\mid (p\!-\!1)!\,$ therefore $\,{\rm mod}\ q\!:\ f((p\!-\!1)!) \equiv \color{#c00}{f(0)\equiv 1},\,$ so $\,q\nmid f((p\!-\!1)!).$

OP is special case $\,p=7,\,\ f(x) = (12!/6!\cdot  x +1)(x+1),\, $ so $\,f(6!) = (12!+1)(6!+1)$

Above we used standard [Congruence Rules,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) most notably the Polynomial Congruence Rule $\, a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, f(a)\equiv f(b)\ \pmod{\! m},\ $ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with integer coefficients.